# How to get Sigma NcR mod 1000000007

Tags: c++, combinations, modulo

I made my self a function on how to do nCr % 1000000007.

I need to actually find

(nCr + n2Cr2 + n3Cr3 +... ) % 1000000007

How do I proceed from here

(nCr%1000000007 + n2Cr2%1000000007 +..) % 1000000007 gives me wrong result..

I tried other combinations but of no work.

Tell me how is this sum done.

Comment: Do you implement your own function to calculate `nCr`? Or are you using a library to do it? Please provide a [mcve] to show us how you do the calculation. Then explain how the actual output differs from what you expect.

Comment: @wally In this context, I think `nCr` signifies ["n choose r"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Comment: Is this a Project Euler problem? Or a problem from a similar coding website?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that make much better sense than Nitrogen-Chromium.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is to note that

```
(a + b) % n == ((a % n) + (b % n)) % n
(a * b) % n == ((a % n) * (b % n)) % n
```

You can use these to reduce the risk of overflow as you calculate `nCr`.

Comment: @JosephWood Not that we know. The OP doesn't show the algorithm to calculate `nCr`. If this is implemented directly from the mathematical definition, it contains many multiplications and easily overflows a 32-bit int for moderate values of `n` and `r`.

Comment: @JosephWood Perhaps this answer is premature since the OP still hasn't answered my first comment under the question.

Comment: I think it is fair to say that this question, as currently presented, is not very clear and should probably be closed.